# How to simplify this kind of code?

Tags: php

This code is properly working. However, I'm thinking of ways to shorten it since I'm still learning PHP. I'm using this snippet to generate a title for an e-mail I am going to send to somebody.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key,'cloud') !== false && !$a) {
        $title .= "CS ";
        $a = true;
    }

    if(strpos($key,'dco') !== false && !$b) {
        $title .= "DC ";
        $b = true;
    }

    if(strpos($key,'comm') !== false && !$c) {
        $title .= "BC ";
        $c = true;
    }

    if(strpos($key,'fiber') !== false && !$d) {
        $title .= "FC ";
        $d = true;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure they do the same thing (all of the if statements). If there's anything you can suggest/advice, please let me know!

Cheers!

Comment: Where do these variables `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d` come from?

Comment: @AmalMurali I think it means that `if` they are not set yet.

Comment: Exactly! Kudos to Daan :)

Comment: @Daan: I'm asking how are they getting initialized. And no, it doesn't mean that. It simply checks if those variables are falsey.

Comment: Nope. I'm trying to check if they exist. I can change that boolean value to anything else.

Comment: You should use `!isset`to check that

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip! I owe ya one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me I think that code is simple enough.

If you're attempting to make the code shorter, you risk making it harder to read.

The one comment I have is don't use generic variable names like `$a`, `$b`, `$c` and `$d`.  Use proper descriptive variable names instead.

It's possible that you could swap the positions of these conditions, that is, change

```
if(strpos($key,'dco') !== false && !$b)
```

to

```
if(!$b && strpos($key,'dco') !== false)
```

But this is more of a micro-optimization than a simplification or change in readability.

Comment: I'm the only one using the snippet so it's okay. I apologize I can't vote up just yet. I'll heed your advice. Thank you!

Comment: "I'm the only one using the snippet so it's okay" - actually when I said that it's better to use descriptive variable names, that's at least as much for *your own* benefit as anybody else's.  So when you come back to the code in 12 months you remember what all those variables mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple create function. This code should work:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    checkstrpos($key,'cloud',$a,$title,"CS ");
    checkstrpos($key,'dco',$b,$title,"DC ");
    checkstrpos($key,'comm',$c,$title,"BC ");
    checkstrpos($key,'fiber',$d,$title,"FC ");
}


function checkstrpos($key,$text, &$variable, &$title, $add) {
    if(strpos($key,$text) !== false && !$variable) {
        $title .= $add;
        $variable = true;
    }        
}
```

Another solution without using references:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    list($title, $a) = checkstrpos($key,'cloud',$a,$title,"CS ");
    list($title, $b) = checkstrpos($key,'dco',$b,$title,"DC ");
    list($title, $c) = checkstrpos($key,'comm',$c,$title,"BC ");
    list($title, $d) = checkstrpos($key,'fiber',$d,$title,"FC ");
}


function checkstrpos($key,$text, $variable, $title, $add) {
    if(strpos($key,$text) !== false && !$variable) {
        $title .= $add;
        $variable = true;
    }   
    return array($title, $variable);     
}
```

Comment: Can't the foreach block be shortened to just 1 line?

Comment: But what for? You can of course create another function and then in foreach you will have only one function, you can of course move everything from your foreach in answer to function but I think this code is the best choice. You see in foreach a bit what's happenning and you can always add another options if you want. Now you have cloud, dco and so on, but some they you may want to add something alse and it's better visible in that way I think

Comment: Sounds convincing. Thank you for this!

Comment: Another question, what's an ampersand doing up there?

Comment: It causes that function won't copy the variable and will work on original variable so it can change its value

Comment: Which is not a very good idea. That can introduce hard to track bugs as code grows.

Comment: Thinking about @vascowhite's concern, it's plausible. I'll remove it then.

Comment: But in this case it makes the code is shorter what author wanted. Also references may be used. It's not a bad practice I think

Comment: I've added another solution it someone doesn't want to use references.

Comment: I didn't think I followed through. I didn't understand what ampersand meant.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without using a function:

```
    $infos = array(
        array('cloud', 'CS', &$a),
        array('dco', 'DC', &$b),
        array('comm', 'BC', &$c),
        array('fiber', 'FC', &$d)
    );

    foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
        foreach($infos as $info) {
            if ( !$info[2] && strpos($k, $info[0]) !== false) {
                $title .= $info[1]. ' ';
                $info[2] = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This isn't the best way though. As suggested in another answer, it'd be better to use a function: an anonymous function (aka closure).